# Android Leak Canary and StreetViewPanoramaFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, leakcanary

I've added Leak Canary to a personal Android application and the following stack trace was generated:

```
05-13 06:49:15.589  27088-28230/com.upwardsnorthwards.blueplaqueslondon D/LeakCanary﹕ In com.upwardsnorthwards.blueplaqueslondon:1.2:3.
* com.upwardsnorthwards.blueplaqueslondon.activities.PanoramaActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT thread com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.streetview.bf.v (named 'Renderer')
* references com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.streetview.f.mParent
* references android.widget.FrameLayout.mParent
* references android.widget.FrameLayout.mContext
* leaks com.upwardsnorthwards.blueplaqueslondon.activities.PanoramaActivity instance
* Reference Key: 9d5d97cd-865a-4f93-92c1-63f7a8589525
* Device: motorola motorola XT1021 condor_tescogb
* Android Version: 4.4.4 API: 19
* Durations: watch=5024ms, gc=236ms, heap dump=745ms, analysis=39070ms
```

The `PanoramaActivity` which is causing this has an `onCreate` method which looks like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_panorama);
    final StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
            (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.street_view_panorama);
    streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        placemark = (Placemark) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(BluePlaquesConstants.PANORAMA_CLICKED_PARCLEABLE_KEY);
    }
}
```

The .xml layout file for this activity looks like:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/street_view_panorama"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My gradle file for the project looks like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:0.4.2'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
}
```

The full source for the application is available at https://github.com/seanoshea/BluePlaquesLondon-Android and I've created an issue to track this at https://github.com/seanoshea/BluePlaquesLondon-Android/issues/69.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Might you be able to suggest a solution?

Cheers,

Sean

Comment: I think that you should not set the Activity instance to streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync.

Comment: I'll admit to copy-and-pasting the example code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/streetview which just uses the Activity as the `OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback`. Would you suggest just creating this callback inline and not implementing the callback interface in the activity?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8028 is the corresponding bug in the Google bug tracker if anyone else is running into this issue.

Comment: Any luck solving this problem?

Comment: @Ahmed trying with the 7.8.0 version of Google play services with Android 4.4 and I'm still getting the same error. Updated the google bug report to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the `StreetViewPanoramaFragment` is retaining a reference to a long-running background task, and your PanoramaActivity is registered as the callback for that fragment.

Give this a shot: separate out the callback into an instance variable, so you don't have to worry about managing the lifecycle of that StreetViewPanoramaFragment:

In PanoramaActivity.java:

```
private OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback mCallback;    

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // do the stuff you described

    mCallback = new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
        // whatever this needs to implement
    };
    streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(mCallback);

    // the rest of your stuff
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mCallback = null;
}
```

I'm not guaranteeing that's the issue, but it could become one. If there's an async task in the background, and you rotate your device, the PanoramaActivity will go away, but *cannot be marked for garbage collection* because it's still retained while waiting for the callback from the streetViewPanoramaFragment.

Comment: Tried this suggestion, but it didn't appear to work unfortunately.